# Error: "Could not find this item" , but file is there

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I have a fat32 external drive, copied some working files in it around a year ago. now when I want to copy back them to the PC (Win 10), I'm getting this error for SOME of files:

[image]

I tried some solutions but nothing worked:

- CMD: Problematic files don't have DOS name, so I cant rename or move them by DOS commands.
- Booted in safe mode. same error.
- Booted via boot disk and using its CMD: no luck.
- Trying UNLOCKER programs, they unlock folder/files, bot nothing changes.
- I CAN change folder names. but that don't solve the problem. (Can't change file names, nor can't open them at all.)
- Files/folders don't have Security tab on their properties. so I cant do anything with permissions.

Comment: Right-vlivk the drive, select Properties, then tools. Run the Error Correction tool **before anything else**.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the command line, you can open an elevated command prompt and type "chkdsk M: /f /r", assuming M: is the name of the drive you're having problems with. If there is no data on the drive, you could try reformatting it.

Comment: @BillDOe Well, I basically wanted to format the drive to NTFS. and problem is exactly what I described.. files are locked there and I cant move them out (I don't have any copy of them) . but I'll try your chkdsk command suggest. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found a working solution. I used a file recovery software that worked with FAT32 file system, and it recovered locked files very well and now I can work with (recovered) files without any problems..

I don't know that I can tell the software name here (rules?) , anyway I decided to tell this as general solution for whose they have similar problem.